# How to drop one specific row from dataframe which has duplicate rownames

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

i just cant find the way to drop specific rows, where ID is identical but the date is the oldest. In the example I want to drop row 1, because ID is identical to row 2 but date is older.

simple example:

```
id=c(1,1,2)
date=c("2012-01-01", "2014-01-01", "2014-04-06")
df <- data.frame(id, date)
```

Thanks 
Jenny

Comment: @akrun row 1 is from 2012, row 2 from 2014. So row 1 is older, hence it should be dropped...

Comment: @user2993610 Suppose if there are more than 2 rows per id, I guess you would want to keep only the most recent (just to make sure...)

Answer (score 3):

Try `duplicated` (assuming that the "date" column is ordered)

```
df[!duplicated(df$id,fromLast=TRUE),]
#  id       date
#2  1 2014-01-01
#3  2 2014-04-06
```

Or a `data.table` option

```
df$date <- as.Date(df$date)
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,if(.N>1) .SD[date!=min(date)] else .SD]
#   id       date
#1:  1 2014-01-01
#2:  2 2014-04-06
```

Or an efficient approach would be (with help from @David Arenburg)

```
unique(setorder(setDT(df), id, -date), by = "id")
#   id       date
#1:  1 2014-01-01
#2:  2 2014-04-06
```

Or

```
setorder(setDT(df), id, -date)[!duplicated(id)]
```

Comment: I think that in the `data.table` version you should just use `unique`, all the rest will be inefficient. Something like `unique(setorder(setDT(df), id, -date), by = "id")`

Comment: Also some variation of `setorder(setDT(df), id, -date)[!duplicated(df$id)]` maybe...

Comment: It's basically your base R answer which will be definitely the most efficient once the data is sorted. All the `group_by` and `by` variations in both `dplyr` and `data.table` will be inefficient for a big data set.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a [dplyr](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html) solution:

```
> library(dplyr)
> df %>% group_by(id) %>% arrange(desc(date)) %>% slice(1)
Source: local data frame [2 x 2]
Groups: id

  id       date
1  1 2014-01-01
2  2 2014-04-06
```

EDIT: A simpler (and also more efficient) approach has been proposed by @David Arenburg in the comments below:

```
> df %>% arrange(id, desc(date)) %>% distinct(id)
```

Note that both solutions actually do not drop the oldest entry but instead select the newest one.

Comment: I would call this: "Here's a *possible* dplyr solution". A more optimal (both by efficiency and simplicity) could be `df %>% arrange(id, desc(date)) %>% distinct(id)`

Comment: I actually somewhat prefer the slower variant, I find it clearer to read, and at least at the moment the documentation of `distinct` gives no indication that this answer is actually guaranteed to give correct results (i.e. it doesn’t specify which element is retained). Of course retaining the first element sounds obvious but this is far from obvious when you consider efficient implementations of `distinct` (i.e. via hashed sets).

Comment: @KonradRudolph, I guess you can get that information from `?unique` which `distinct` tries to mimic.

Comment: @David I don’t think this is specific enough to be trusted. `unique` has very different semantics because you cannot specify a key column – all columns are used to determine uniqueness. So it doesn’t actually matter which row is removed (except for the row name). For `distinct` it’s crucial, and should absolutely be documented (tempted to file a bug report, actually).